# Why do some Sharingan eyes have unique Mangekyou abilities?

Tags: naruto

Itachi, Sasuke, Madara's Sharingan and Danzo's "Sharingan" eyes have the "standard" Mangekyou abilities of Amaterasu, Tsukuyomi, Susanoo, Izanagi and Izanami. (Granted not all of them have used all the abilities.)

However, Shisui and Obito's sharingan have unique Mangekyou abilities (Komoamatsukami and Kamui respectively). Why do some Sharingan eyes come with unique abilities? Do they get these abilities in lieu of the standard abilities or in addition to them?

Obito has always used Kamui and never been shown using the standard abilities, with *his* Sharingan (he once used Izanagi with a transplanted Sharingan), which makes me wonder if the special abilities are in lieu of the standard ones.

Comment: The spoiler markup seems to be not working for multiple paragraphs. If someone knows how to do it, please edit it. That would also help me learn.

Comment: I'm not sure if that was what you wanted. But it was not working because you had your sentences broken up into several lines. If you want to do it with that formatting you had before, you'll need to add double-space at the end of each line and a >! at the beginning of each new line. That way I think it'll work. Hope this helped! :D

Comment: @JNat Thanks, this is indeed what I wanted. I forgot about the 2 spaces thing of markdown. :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Each Mangekyo is given a different eye pattern, and a different ability. *Mangekyo* literally translates to *kaleidoscope*, where each time you look you see a different, symmetric shape.

- Itachi had access to Amaterasu and Tsukuyomi
- Sasuke used Amaterasu and Kagutsuchi, which allowed him to shape and control his Amaterasu
- Obito has Kamui. Obito also uses "throw-away" Sharingan eyes for Izanagi.
- Shisui has a different one, the Kotoamatsukami.
- Madara's ,Izuna's, and Indra's eye techniques were not revealed.
- Kakashi has Kamui as well, since it's technically Obito's eye.
- Danzo can use Shisui's Kotoamatsukami, since he has his eye. It's unknown if he can also any other Mangekyo Sharingan abilities with it (like Amaterasu or Tsukuyomi).

#### Also

- Susano'o is achieved once you control both of the techniques in your eyes, regardless of what they are. That's the reason Kakashi (And Obito) for instance cannot ever achieve a Susano'o individually, but could when

> Obito's spirit possessed Kakashi and gave him both Mangekyo Sharingan

Which technique you gain isn't "predetermined". You cannot discern it before you gain the Mangekyo and it seems to be random, however it may be linked to an individual's personality and skill set - Itachi was incredibly skilled with Genjutsu, and gained the Tsukuyomi. Sasuke was shown to be very skilled with Fire Release jutsu and for much of the anime had a burning hatred inside of him, which may be why he gained incredible control over his Amaterasu. This is pure speculation however.

Many people have been speculating that Madara had to have the Tsukuyomi due to his use of Genjutsu on Oonoki, however all Sharingan users, whether or not they have the Mangekyo, can cast Genjutsu simply via eye-contact. The strength of this varies with the strength of the user, but with how powerful Madara is, his Genjutsu: Sharingan approaching Tsukuyomi levels of strength would not be unreasonable.

Additionally, Izanagi and Izanami are both jutsu that can be used by simple Sharingan users, without need of a Mangekyo or Senju DNA.

Ref: http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sharingan , http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Mangeky%C5%8D_Sharingan

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had a mistaken assumption that Izanagi and Izanami are techniques *beyond* Susanoo, but I read the manga again, and as you said, Mangekyou is indeed not necessary. Sasuke did mention once that one needs to have control over Amaterasu and Tsukuyomi to use Susanoo, but in the light of what you mentioned, he was likely referring to just himself. It is interesting though to note that Obito and Shisui have the same technique in both eyes. Also, if Obito had not gifted his left eye to Kakashi, he would have been able to use Susanoo. Interesting.

Comment: Now that 1 year has passed, this answer can be updated :D We can update Obito's , Kakashi's, and Madara's techniques. On that note, it is somewhat strange that the left eye generally has a different technique from the right eye, but not in Shisui's case.

Comment: @krikara: Actually, not we can't. Obito's has a different technique from the others. Madara's techniques were still not revealed (apart from the Susanoo, which is implied to be there for all maximum potential Mangekyos).

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Not sure what you mean. Obito has Kamui, same with Kakashi. As for Madara's techniques, see my explanation comment for user2042. We know he can use both Tsukuyomi and Amaterasu.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: are you really sure that Susano'o can be activated as soon as you control both techniques in your eyes, regardless of what they are?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha have they revealed what unique ability Madarar's sharingan has?

Comment: This "answer" has a lot of misinformation. Sasuke doesn't have Tsukuyomi. Being related doesn't necessarily have any bearing on the Mangekyo techniques -- Sasuke had Amaterasu and Kagutsuchi, which allowed him to control Amaterasu rather than just creating it. Izanagi doesn't require Senju cells, as Madara used it to "negate" his death without having Senju cells ((he had Hashi's skin but it hadn't been integrated into his body yet)). Tobi had his Mangekyo when he used Izanagi, but he activated Izanagi with a spare Sharingan he had.

Comment: @RFKomos Sounds like a good candidate for editing. Feel free to [edit] this answer with more accurate info.

Answer (score 9):

To perform Izanagi and Izanami, only a regular Sharingan is required (although Izanagi is further perfected when used in combination with Senjuu cells or genes).

Susano'o is "the strength of the tempestuous force that resides only within those of have mastered"<sup>1</sup>:

- Amaterasu, "representing the light of the material world"<sup>1</sup>.
- Tsukuyomi, "the nightmare realm, representing the world of the mind and darkness"<sup>1</sup>.

This means that any shinobi known to have used Susano'o, must have have mastered both Amaterasu (with his right eye) and Tsukuyomi (with his left eye) beforehand. Given this, unlike what [Madara's answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/848/49) suggests, the latter two techniques are not unique to Itachi and Sasuke, since Uchiha Madara has been seen to use the Susano'o. This means that, although it remains yet to be seen, he *must have* mastered Amaterasu and Tsukuyomi before.

As for the origin of the more "particular" Mangekyou abilities, there seems to be no reliable source from which one can take conclusions. However, one can speculate:

- They can be some sort of mutations. Shisui's Kotoamatsukami seems to be *unique to him*, not rare, which could mean that he had some particularity that allowed him to develop this technique.
- Obito's Kamui may have developped due to the fact that the eyes were "separated" (one with him and the other with Kakashi). As the series develops, we see that the jutsu is the same, but has some particularities depending on which eye uses it. This could mean that each of the users (Obito and Kakashi) may have somehow adapted the technique, or that Kakashi's technique is much weaker and has more downsides due to the fact that he is not an Uchiha.
- Still regarding Kamui, the databook states that "with proficiency, it becomes a frightening jutsu that can suck a person whole into another world." My interpretation of this (especially the "with proficiency" part) is that with enough proficiency, **Kakashi** can master this frightening technique. However, the [Naruto Wiki page on Kamui](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kamui#Trivia) seems to interpret this as: with enough proficiency, **any Mangekyou Sharingan user** can master this frightening technique.
- As for whether these "special" techniques are presented as a plus or as a substitute to the "basic Mangekyou techniques", there is also no information. But, given the fact that we never saw either Kakashi or Obito using any of the "basic techniques", I think it is relatively safe to assume that they are present *in lieu* of them.

---

<sup>1</sup>[Naruto: The Official Character Databook](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Naruto-Official-Character-Data-Book/dp/1421541254/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1362417911&sr=8-1)

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, I'd venture to guess that Tsukiyomi, Amaterasu, and Susanoo are a set of techniques that rarely occur among the Uchiha. Madara was famed for the use of the techniques, I suppose. Following this, it has been said that Itachi and Sasuke are far more than *average*, *normal*, or *standard* Uchiha, they seem to be exceptional Shinobi, even by Uchiha "standards". This may be partly because of their *unique* Sharingan, being able to access the Trifecta Tsuki-Amate-Susa combination. We, the fans, see this Trifecta as being the *norm* for Sharingan, when in fact they are likely a rarity among the Uchiha clan.

Comment: This is true. Obito stated that Susanoo is a rare occurrance for Uchiha. That means Amaterasu and Tsukuyomi are also rare.

Answer (score 3):

Madara also can also use Tsukuyomi as his objective is to use infinite tsukuyomi which would only be possible if he possesses Tsukuyomi.

Maybe he could also use Amaterasu? That's why he could pull off his Susano'o. So, these three abilities (At least two) seem to be possessed by all Mangekyō users granted they have awoken them.

Maybe Shisui, Obito and Kakashi discover their unique abilities before these three. Hence, it can be deduced that either most Mangekyō have the same abilities and due to some unknown reasons some also have a special one.

Or it could be that Madara's, Sasuke's, and Itachi's unique Mangekyō abilities have yet to be shown. Or Kishi is just mad. Or maybe I am?

Comment: It's not certain that Madara can use Tsukuyomi, Remember the Obito is trying to use it, and he can't use Tsukuyomi. It's an interesting theory though.

Comment: Madara can in fact use Tsukuyomi. The Eye of Moon plan is using the moon to reflect his own sharingan, casting Tsukuyomi on everyone. Additionally, Tsukuyomi (and Amaterasu) is required to awaken Susanoo as stated by Sasuke. While Sasuke may have just been referring to himself and not MS users in a general sense, Japanese mythology depicts Amaterasu, Tsukuyomi, and Susanoo as siblings. Thus it is safe to say Sasuke's statement works in a general sense.

Comment: @krikara: Need I remind you that Obito tried to pull off the Eye of the Moon as well (and he almost succeeded)? Obito doesn't have Tsukuyomi, both his eyes have a slightly different version of Kamui.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Considering all cases, we really don't know *how* Obito planned to do it, whether it using the Shinju's, Madara's, or Sasuke's eye. But let us assume he wasn't going to use Madara at all for his plan. We still have two indicators that Madara can use Tsukuyomi: Sasuke's statement and Japanese mythology. And this excludes Obito's original statement, where he says reflecting one's eye for execution.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha
Madara did use Tsukuyomi against the Raikage, In the 5vs1 battle.

Comment: @MphLee Nope, that wasn't Tsukuyomi, it was a normal Genjutsu: Sharingan, just like Sasuke used. As far as we know, Tsukuyomi is as unique to Itach as Kotoamatsukami is unique to Shisui.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I'm not sure, I'll check again. I know that we actually can't see in the scene how that Genjutsu looked to the raikage, but I this doesn't exclude that it was the Tsukuyomi: Tsukuyomi from an external point of view last few seconds, as in the 5vs1 battle, but yeah, even in sasuke vs Killer B it looks the same, but it was not the Tsukuyomi. 
I'll check better anyways.

Comment: @MphLee Tsukuyomi cannot be broken by an external ally ("Release!") because it distorts the victim's sense of time. Thus ending within a few seconds (few days in the victim's mind). Madara put the Raikage under genjutsu in order to hit him more easily, and Onoki released it, which shouldn't be possible.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Ah oke! I didn't know that (that Tsukuyomi can't be broken).

Comment: @MphLee Kakashi says that to Chyo when they battle (projected) Itachi when rushing to rescue Gaara. Chyo presents with the common battle plan against Dojutsu users. One ally falls to the Genjutsu, while the other attacks the user from behind, then releasing the jutsu. But Kakashi tells her it won't work because Tsukuyomi is too potent, as one stare would "insta-kill" any ally in 3 seconds, without the possibility of a release.

Answer (score 2):

Following the manga, susanoo is only achieved by those who can use both, tsukuyomi and amatarasu. Japanese folk lore provides further insight to this because the three "techniques" are named after 3 "gods" who are siblings. We can infer that madara can use amatarasu since he is seen using both susanoo and tsukuyomi. On a side note, either purposely or through error, itachi is shown using susanoo without his mangekyo sharingan active, and madara is shown using it while using the rennegan. This leads me to believe that susanoo can be used at any time without the sharingan being active as long as amatarasu and tsukuyomi can be used. Further, an above answer suggests that obito's kamui is the only ability of his mangekyo sharingan. However, due to his attempt to use eye of the moon without madara, I think it's also safe to assume he can also use tsukuyomi. Should be noted however, the ten tails is NEEDED to complete the jutsu, and ITS eye is reflected on the moon, not the user, which could mean infinite tsukuyomi could be a seperate jutsu only usable by the ten tails and it's jinchiriki. Also should be noted obito used a small scale version of this technique in one of the movies, which drew naruto and Sakura into another "dream world". A small orb was present during the casting, which could lead to it being an entirely seperate, although similarly named, technique.

Unfortunately though, with the information we have, there is currently no definitive answer to weither or not there are an actual set of techniques possible for all sharingan users to unlock, or if the abilities between sharingan users themselves are unique.

We do have manga quotes stating that madara itachi and sasuke are exceptional among their kin, and we know they all can use amatarasu tsukuyomi and because of that susanoo. We also have manga quotes that say these techniques are rare within their clan. It is the lack of uchiha that make the techniques seem like the "norm" 
Because 3 of the 5 uchiha who's techniques are known to us are the previously mentioned set. I'll save my issues with probability and chance lol.

Also, clearing up an above answer, madara was reanimated (edo tensai) with both eyes and in his "prime". Meaning all the techniques he had aquired during his lifetime would be able to be employed, including his aquiring hashiramas cells, and rennegan despite his aquiring the later on his deathbed. It was on his deathbed prior to his meeting obito, that transplanted BOTH of his rennegan eyes to nagato, and began to set his eye of moon plan into action. It was with the help of obito and black zetsu (madara's will) that the would influence nagato into his actions during the sage arc, and would bring to fruition the seemingly foiled plan. When the jinchiriki were captured and had their respective tailed beasts pulled from them, they died (exception garaa who died and was revived). They were reanimated (edo tensai) and reinfused with the tailed beast chakra, while the beasts themselves seemed to be sealed in the gedo statue, despite the former jinchiriki being able to use full beast transformations. Apparent from son goku being freed from the chakra rods embedded in him, but still being sealed in the statue, and proven at the dismissal of the edo tensai and the jinchiriki with no effect of the beasts themselves.

Finally, when madara is brought back into his real life body, he has NO EYES, until zetsu recovers the rennegan obito was using which was originally madara's.

Answer (score 2):

Sharingan is activated by emotional distress as recently explained by the edo tensei hokages. Chakra from the brain hat is reflected in the eyes. My guess is intelligence and the level of emotional distress contributes to an ability. Something of note, Kishi loves his bloodline abilities and clan related abilitites. Iwould not be surprised if a bloodline plays a role in sharingan abilities. Recently it is mentioned that Sasuke resembles Madara's brother...

Answer (score 2):

The abilities of the eyes are determined by the users skill and there own training. Amaterasu was given to Sasuke by Itachi and in his other eye he implanted blaze control so that he could incorporate Amaterasu into has chidori and as an example Sasuke was able to use part of Susano'o before he had blaze control and Amaterasu.

And to clear something up the user does not have to have Amaterasu or Tsukuyomi, they only have to master the two abilities that they chose to implant into there eyes through concentration and training which is shown when Kakashi uses Susano'o

Answer (score 1):

From the beginning the Mangekyou is seen as a mutation, mutations can have rarer mutations added unto themselves.

Itachi was always known for mastery of Genjutsu so he was better with Tsukuyomi even though he could also use Amaterasu. So his eyes are attuned to that.
Sasuke on the other hand was better with Fire Style jutsu, thusly becoming more acquainted with Amaterasu. So his eyes are attuned to fire control.

Madara, being the first Uchiha to awaken the Mangekyou mastered both on his own as well. Because he's.. Madara. It is fair to assume, however that his brother was attuned to Genjustsu while he was attuned to fire(since he's known for his use of Amaterasu) and when he got his brother's eyes he gained better control over both.

Given the limited evidence we have we can only assume that Tsukuyomi, Amaterasu and Susano'o are the norm but rarer mutations do exist.

Obito and Shisui have their own special abilities, they're unable to use the other abilities but they have their own unique ones, their own mutations. Obito is the stranger case because his eyes have their own unique quirk to Kamui. Kakashi's can be used to teleport things outside of himself while Obito's can be used on himself. This is probably because they were meant to be together. If Obito had both his eyes he'd be invincible pretty much. His abilities were created to complement each other.

Answer (score 1):

spoilers they have unique sharingan abilities because people are unique.

and to the guy who said that madara only transplanted his right eye to nagato. No HE DID NOT
he transplanted both eyes to Nagato when Nagato was so young he did not remember it.. he then used replacement eyes that he got from someone else. thats why nagato had both eyes.
he had the sharingan and Rinnegan while in Edo Tensei mode because the Edo Tensei brings a 
person back in there living form. when he was revived with Rinne Tensei he had no eyes because  1 eye was in nagato and the other was in Obito 
and the reason he could use susanoo still was because susanoo is a spiritual ethereal creature made of pure chakra summoned by a sharingan user who has has mastered a unique mangekyou sharingan ability in each eye

and for the guy who wandered how he could use susanoo while he had his Rinnegan active its easy. he awakened the Rinnegan naturally(albeit in a cheating manner) so his eyes evolved from pure EMS to an to the Rinnegan the completed Rinnegan has the full power of both sharingan and Rinnegan the reason is because the sages son Indra inherited his eyes in the form of the sharingan(because the Sharingan actually predates the Rinnegan and was one of 2 dojutsu the sages mom had(byakugan and Sharingan)

Answer (score 1):

The normal abilities of the Mangekyou Sharingan are Amaterasu and Tsukuyomi. However, there are not many Mangekyou sharigan users. If the user are skilled in genjutsu the user will eventually be able to use the Tsukuyomi better. For example Itachi was skilled in Tsukuyomi and that's why he can use it so well. Shisui was the best in genjutsu before attaining the Mangekyou sharingan so when he got the MS, he enhanced the genjutsu, forming Kotoamatsukami. Sasuke cannot use the Tsukuyomi as well as Itachi, but Itachi implanted his already skilled use of Amaterasu in Sasuke, so that's why Sasuke could use Amaterasu so well.

When Obito gained his Mangekyou sharingan he somehow gained his own special power called Kamui. His left eye is what Kakashi has and it's a long range power, whereas Obito's left eye is short range.

When the Mangekyou sharingan user can use the powers of the 2 eyes they may unlock the Susanno. Shisui's Kotoamatsukami used his two eyes; that's why he can use Susanno also.

Hoped this helped!

Comment: I edited your post to make it more clear and easier to read. If I cut anything important, you can change it back.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this as a spoiler if you haven't found out yet.

Madara performed Tsukuyomi on Raikage on the episode he revealed his perfect Susanoo. The manga also mentioned that Madara gave his left eye to Nagato without him knowing, which was later taken by Obito. However, he had a spare left eye possibly, and yet not a right since he said he could take Obito's if Obito dies. Although Madara was reanimated with a fake right eye, it is still possible for him to use his Susanoo. A similar case would be where the Jinchuriki were reanimated with their Kyubi, even though the Akatsuki extracted the Kyubi from them before death. Once an Uchiha activate their trump card Susanoo, they can even use it while blind. So as long as they awakened Susanoo before death, they can be reanimated with it, but since it's fake, he probably couldn't unlock its true power of Amaterasu.

Comment: And by the way madara lost his right eye by somebody I forgot he mentioned while discussing with crippled obito