# Can Sasuke use Tsukuyomi?

Tags: naruto

The question is based on my theory from the recent manga chapter (Naruto 661):

> Sasuke, when stabbed by Madara is the effect of Tsukuyomi from Sasuke.

Now, to prove my theory, is there an episode in manga/anime that Sasuke used Tsukuyomi?

Comment: I beleive I have answered your question.....please do check it out ;)

Comment: I have got a question..... why do you think it was Tsukiyome from Sasuke?Couldn't it be a normal genjutsu itself? I am questioning you this since Sasuke decomposed his body while he fought against Deidara.....at that point of time he didn't had Itachi's eyes.......

Comment: Sasuke can NOT use Tsukuyomi. Just read the talks page at the Naruto wiki. There is a hell lot of confusion among people regarding this. The accepted answer is outdated. The wiki it refers to, has updated its content to show the correct information now.
Go to [Tsukuyomi](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Tsukuyomi) page in Naruto wiki. See the list of users.

Comment: Each sharingan - eye can only have one 'special ability', as mentioned below the two Sasuke has are - Amaterasu & the control of the flames of Amaterasu

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Short answer

Sasuke can not use Tsukuyomi.

1. When fighting Kabuto, Sasuke used a regular Sharingan genjutsu on Itachi.
2. Sasuke's left eye creates Amaterasu, and his right eye manipulates the flames. There is no place for Tsukuyomi.

## Long answer

Mostly from a reddit [post](http://www.reddit.com/r/Naruto/comments/2i6hgr/why_sasuke_does_not_have_the_tsukuyomi/):

Sasuke does not have the Tsukuyomi. **What Sasuke uses is the Sharingan's standard ability to cast genjutsu through eye contact with its "eye of hypnosis"**. In the past, Sasuke had personally it used on Sai, Orochimaru and Deidara, and we've seen it used by Itachi, Kakashi, Obito and Madara on different occasions. What Sasuke had been doing since Itachi's death was channeling these Sharingan Genjutsu through his Mangekyou Sharingan, which apparently had the effect of amplifying its strength, rendering him capable of instantly incapacitating his opponents.

Sasuke was shown casting genjutsu with one eye of his Mangekyou, like how Itachi cast Tsukuyomi with his left eye (and Amaterasu with his right). But whilst Sasuke typically cast it with his right eye, he had also done it with his left eye. Against C too since he appeared to be holding his left eye, and a third time, if you count his domination of the bijuu.

And even regular Sharingan Genjutsu had been used through a single eye, as demonstrated by Madara and Itachi. Itachi himself used Sharingan Genjutsu with the Mangekyou after his Tsukuyomi eye had been blinded. Madara had done the same.

**Sasuke has never once called his genjutsu, Tsukuyomi.** Both Danzo and Tobi compared it to Itachi's Tsukuyomi - which was understandable since they're brothers and both had used Amaterasu and Susanoo - but neither of them actually called it Tsukuyomi. Only twice had Sasuke "named" it where he called it "Sharingan" and "Genjutsu - Sharingan" respectively (just like Madara). When he called it "Genjutsu - Sharingan", the difference is also made explicit by showing it side-by-side with Itachi's Tsukuyomi.

Tobi implied that Sasuke had received Itachi's eye techniques, but Itachi had only sealed a single use of the Amaterasu inside Sasuke with the Transcription Seal: Amaterasu which Sasuke had no actual control over. From what I've heard, it came from a misunderstanding over how the Japanese language doesn't differentiate between singular and plural. And when the jutsu was unsealed, his eye transformed into Itachi's Mangekyou Sharingan temporarily. So if Sasuke used a Tsukuyomi (or another Amaterasu) from Itachi, his eyes would have changed to show it.

The genjutsu Sasuke used against B (when he still had to implant Itachi's eyes) resembles the Tsukuyomi with its inverted colours, but this was also the only time it happened. Every other time we saw the genjutsu itself, it didn't have that visual effect. It was also said by Itachi and the second databook that the **Tsukuyomi can only be broken by his own blood** (presumably someone of the Uchiha bloodline with a powerful Sharingan), which we later saw proven and explained. **Yet B was essentially freed with just a genjutsu dispel.**

Ultimately, Sasuke only has Amaterasu, Kagutsuchi and Susanoo with his Mangekyou Sharingan. Amaterasu was first used with his left eye against Killer B. Kagutsuchi was used to quell the flames and then used and named it against the Raikage where he shaped the black flames and dubbed it "Enton: Kagutsuchi". **The most blatant evidence of these two being his Mangekyou jutsu is when he fought Kaguya and freed himself from ice using both of his eyes.**

Even after Sasuke took Itachi's eyes to awaken the Eternal Mangekyou Sharingan, he has never revealed the Tsukuyomi. You can implant the Mangekyou Sharingan and use the abilities of the original holder (e.g. Kakashi using Kamui or Danzo using Kotoamatsukami), but when those eyes are used to evolve to the next stage, it instead empowers their own abilities from what we've seen. Or at least removes the drawbacks.

Once the third databook stated that you would need Amaterasu and Tsukuyomi to awaken the Susanoo, but the above tells us that this is outdated information. If anything, I'd believe that Kishimoto had originally intended to give Sasuke the same jutsu as his brother (with different preferences, perhaps) but decided otherwise at crunch time. As far as we know, the only character with the Tsukuyomi is Uchiha Itachi.

Also, the current revision of [Tsukuyomi](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Tsukuyomi) from Naruto Wiki shows only Itachi Uchiha under the list of users.

Comment: @Downvoters You guys should bring in evidence and argue for your point. This only shows your ignorance of the manga.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I think it is a kneejerk reaction at you saying the proof is Naruto Wiki. Can you add some headings or bold to highlight different sections in your answer?

Comment: Look at my edited post below.

Comment: @AmanSingh There are too many flaws in your statement. You're assuming that Sasuke used a simple illusion versus Tsukuyomi in the Danzou fight. There is no proof of this. Your logic also doesn't make sense when you reason that Sasuke should have 3 MS techniques in the event that Tsukuyomi transfers over. Shisui's eyes came with Shisui's techniques. Same for Obito's eyes. How could you prove otherwise for Itachi's eyes? You simply can't, therefore there is no real substance behind your idea. Claiming he used normal genjutsus because he never explicitly said `Tsukuyomi` does not prove him unable

Comment: Also, you should cite your answers when you directly copy and paste them from other sources.

Comment: @krikara Sure. Added the ref.

Comment: @krikara Let me tell you something about a little thing called the burden of proof. Suppose you say there is a god, the burden of proof is on you. You have to prove it explicitly, by citing evidence. You CAN NOT say that since I can not show otherwise, therefore god has to exist. Similarly, in this case, you have to show me explicit evidence from the manga showing me Sasuke saying the words "Tsukuyomi", or atleast using it to manipulate time in someone's mind. I am not assuming that Sasuke is using a normal genjutsu,

Comment: @krikara You can not say that "Since nothing in manga proves him to be unable, therefore he has to be able". Its not logical. There is simply no reason to believe that he has used Tsukuyomi here or anywhere else. Given the scenes from this fight (and EVERY fight he was in), it is a reasonable deduction that he wasn't using Tsukuyomi, based on the very apparent fact, as I have countless times: "Tsukuyomi has to manipulate time in the victim's mind". YOU have the burden of proof. I am merely stating that whatever "evidence" you presented, was inconclusive in this matter. That's all.

Comment: @AmanSingh I already have the proof. He has Itachi's eyes. Like Madara's Rinnegan, Shisui's Sharingan, and Obito's Sharingan, they all retained their powers when transferred to another user (Pain, Danzou, and Kakashi respectively). Prove that Itachi's ocular abilities are not bound to his eyes unlike all the others.

Comment: @krikara If you had read my comments completely, I had explained it plainly and in detail, that the manga does not give us any more details regarding MS transfer. Only 2 kinds of transfers have happened: 1) Both the eyes have same power, and used by non-Uchiha (both Obito and Shisui) 2) Both eyes have different powers and used by sibling (2 cases, only Itachi's case is useful, as we don't know what powers Madara or Izuna had before and after the  MS transfer). Read the whole theory and reason behind it my comments to your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23732/discussion-between-aman-singh-and-krikara).

Answer (score 7):

I believe Sasuke did use Tsukuyomi while he fought against Hachibi. **Bee was immobilized for a moment**

[image: Tsukuyomi Effect on Hachibi]

As per the definition of Tsukuyomi in wiki it states that:

> Tsukuyomi is noted to be one of the most powerful genjutsu in existence.It is unique to the Uchiha clan and only those who have awakened the Mangekyō Sharingan can perform it. It is said to represent the "Spiritual World and Darkness" (精神界と闇, Seishinkai to Yami), the antipode to Amaterasu — a ninjutsu of similar power.

The wiki also states the disadvantages of the technique:

> Such a powerful technique is not without its disadvantages however. Due to the complexity of the illusion and the quickness with which it is executed, an enormous amount of chakra is necessary and an added amount of stress is placed on the left eye, leaving Itachi's vision more blurred. Before using it on Kakashi in Part I, Itachi stated that Tsukuyomi can only be broken by a Sharingan user that shares the same blood as him; as demonstrated when Sasuke overcame Itachi's Tsukuyomi in their battle.

**Itachi casting Tsukuyomi on Kakashi**

[image: Itachi casting Tsukuyomi on Kakashi]

**Both Sasuke and Itachi had to go through a lot of pain while casting it. It consumed a lot of their chakra. Obvious disadvantages were blurred vision after use.**

And last but not the least, the wiki also states that:

> **Sasuke can also perform Tsukuyomi with his right eye**, though his illusion is considered inferior to Itachi's Tsukuyomi since it does not alter the opponent's perception of time indicating he has yet to master it

In the wiki page, it also states that **the users who can cast Tsukuyomi are**:

1. Uchiha Itachi
2. Uchiha Sasuke
3. Uchiha Madara
4. Uchiha Obito [in movie]

### Reference

- [**Tsukuyomi**](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Tsukuyomi?file=Tsukuyomi-sharingan-genjutzu.jpg)

Comment: Do you have a proof that he uses Tsukuyomi?

Comment: @NaraShikamaru hope i have provided enough proof now!!!!!!

Comment: Ok. Got it!..:)

Comment: Note that the wiki now only list Uchiha Itachi as the single user of this technique.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, he can.**

Besides everything else that has been pointed out on other answers here trying to prove that Sasuke can use the Tsukuyomi, I'd just like to point out a piece of **information that comes straight from [*Naruto: The Official Character Databook*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Naruto-Official-Character-Data-Book/dp/1421541254/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1362417911&sr=8-1)**, pointed out in [this answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/13336/49) and in [this one](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/2784/49) before it:

- Amaterasu, "representing the light of the material world", is performed with the right eye.
- Tsukuyomi, "the nightmare realm, representing the world of the mind and darkness", is performed with the left eye.
- **Susano'o** is "the strength of the tempestuous force that **resides only within those of have mastered" both of the above techniques**.

Notice that you have to master *both* Amaterasu and Tsukuyomi in order to be able to perform Susano'o. This means that Indra, Itachi, Madara, Kakashi and **Sasuke** must be able to perform both Amaterasu *and* Tsukuyomi - even if we haven't seen them doing it ever - since they all can use Susano'o.

Either that, or the official databook has incorrect data. [Aman Singh's answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/15018/49) is also very compelling, and makes some good points.

Comment: There is this part in the Naruto wiki: `In the third databook, Tsukuyomi and Amaterasu were stated to be requirements for unlocking Susanoo. However, Sasuke instead defined Susanoo as the third power granted to users of the Double Mangekyō, and Sasuke's explanation was once again verified by Kakashi's usage of the technique.` http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Susanoo

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: It's really simple to be quite honest. Sasuke has Itachi's eyes. Itachi's eyes are capable of using of Tsukuyomi. Therefore Sasuke can use Tsukuyomi.

This stays consistent with the rest of the manga, for example how people can take the Rinnegan and use it for themselves like Tobi x Pain. Danzou took Shisui's eyes and then used Shisui's MS power for himself as well.

---

Here is the proof that Sasuke actually used Tsukuyomi.

Recall the fight versus Danzou. Sasuke casted Tsukuyomi on Danzou and Danzou proceeds to comment on it.
[image]

As for your theory, there is one easy criteria you can use for confirmation. Techniques like Amaterasu and Tsukuyomi cause excessive eye strain, which leads into bleeding. When Sasuke used Amaterasu on Madara, his eyes also bled. When Sasuke stabbed the sword through Madara, there were no signs of bleeding, and therefore we can determine he did not use Tsukuyomi there.

[image]

Comment: I can't believe people still don't get it. Where have you seen Sasuke manipulate time in Danzou's mind (That is what Tsukuyomi does you know)? That genjutsu was a simple iluusion to test whether Danzou can be put into genjutsu or not, as Tobi himself said later. And where exactly has Danzou said that Sasuke used Tsukuyomi? He is comparing that pathetic little genjutsu to Itachi's Tsukuyomi. That's all.
BTW, having his brother's eyes does not guarantee Tsukuyomi at all. If that were the case, Sasuke would have 3 MS techniques! (Amaterasu, Enton Kagutsuchi, and Tsukuyomi).

Comment: Also, since we don't have enough instances of Sharingans being transplanted with their powers known, we can't say exactly what happens in each case. E.g. if both the MS of a user have same power (Like Shisui and Obito, it seems whoever gets the eye, gets the power as well (like Itachi and Danzou (from Shisui), and Madara himself from Obito). In case there are two powers, there has only been the case of Itachi, and we haven't EVER seen Sasuke use Tsukuyomi on ANYONE (except ofcourse channeling his genjustu through his MS to amplify its power). Only Amaterasu, and his own Enton.

Comment: All in all, the only conclusion that we can draw from manga is, "Anyone who acquires someone else MS, gets only one of their eye's power". There is no evidence to deny this, and it does explain all the MS transplants.

Comment: @AmanSingh That's easily disproven. Kakashi had used both of Obito's eyes and had both powers. Your claim is only your assumption.

Comment: What "both" powers? Obito's MS had only one power.

Comment: Even if it were the case that Sasuke got Tsukuyomi from Itachi's eyes, he shouldn't be able to use that here, as the transplant happened later on, and the technique that Itachi taught to Sasuke's MS was just Amaterasu, and that too was not under control of Sasuke at the time.

Answer (score 2):

I can't remember exactly, but when Itachi (Edo Tensei) and Sasuke battled Kabuto in the cave, they were trapped at the same time in a genjutsu. They undid it by using genjutsu on each other. I'm sure that Itachi used Tsukuyomi, but I'm not sure if Sasuke's genjutsu was a normal one or a Tsukuyomi. However, I'm sure that Itachi used Tsukuyomi at least once when he fought Danzo...

By the way, it's a fact that you must be able to use Amaterasu and Tsukuyomi to achieve Susano'o, so the answer for your question is yes, Sasuke can use Tsukuyomi for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Sasuke definitely CAN'T use Tsukuyomi!

It's a manga/anime! That means it follows some rules. If Sasuke were able to use Tsukuyomi, then the technique would be introduced properly, like when they introduced Amaterasu and Kagutsuchi.

However, Sasuke didn't say "Tsukuyomi" even once (!!!) in the whole manga! Why did he always scream "Amaterasu" and "Kagutsuchi", but not "Tsukuyomi" even once?! It doesn't make any sense!

Furthermore, every Uchiha has one technique in each eye.
It's clearly said that one of his eyes has Amaterasu, and the other one has Enton: Kagutsuchi.
There is no place for Tsukuyomi!

(For Susanoo you need both eyes' powers, but it doesn't matter if it's Amaterasu and Enton Kagutsuchi or Tsukuyomi)

Comment: Please refer to http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Blaze_Release:_Kagutsuchi

Answer (score 0):

Sasuke can't use Tsukuyomi, it's just a manga and anime fact.

The user of the MS must awaken the abilities of both eyes to achieve the Susano'o, it isn't specifically Amaterasu or Tsukuyomi. Also, Sasuke can use genjutsu..but not the Tsukuyomi. With his left eye, Sasuke can cast Amaterasu, with his right he can shape and manipulate the flames. Those are his two abilities, Tsukuyomi has no spot.

In the Manga, Sasuke states that Susano'o can only be awakened when someone awakens both powers in their eyes, Tsukuyomi and Amaterasu belong to Itachi only. As a parting gift, Itachi gave Sasuke the Amaterasu.

Answer (score 0):

Sasuke can't use it, and if he had used it on Danzo and Killer Bee, they wouldn't have been able to escape it without Sasuke releasing them from it.

Itachi states that only someone with Uchiha genetics and the Sharingan can undo the Tsukuyomi. This is a manga fact, meaning Sasuke never used Tsukuyomi. Sasuke may have Itachi's eyes, but it's never been stated that the abilities of the eyes are transferred through the Eternal Mangekyo Sharingan. Seeing as though Madara is the only other person with the EMS, and the fact that he has no unique Mangekyo abilities, proves that abilities really aren't transferred through the EMS.

The Tsukuyomi is only used by Itachi, stop making up theories because it *seems* possible.