# Why can't Sasuke use Tsukuyomi even after implanting Itachi's eyes?

Tags: naruto

The manga makes it plenty clear that Sasuke can/does not use Tsukuyomi. Both his eyes have powers related to Amaterasu only. But why? Madara and Kakashi could use Kamui using Obito's eyes and Danzo could use KotoAmatsukami using Shisui's eyes. Then why not Sasuke? We have seen that during fight with Kabuto, he uses ordinary sharingan genjutsu on Itachi when freeing him from Kabuto's sound genjutsu.

Does this mean that once you achieve your own MS powers, implanting someone else's eyes does not grant you their power but just give you EMS?

Does the eye transplant work differently for non-Uchihas, as in they just gain the original eye power?

But this still does not explain Madara's using Kamui.

Edit: People seem to be confused about the fact that Sasuke can NOT use Tsukuyomi. Here is the detailed answer I wrote: https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/15018/9123

Here is a [Tsukuyomi wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Tsukuyomi) that clearly states the only user is Uchiha Itachi

Comment: Have fun reading [this](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6926/can-sasuke-use-tsukuyomi) hope it clears your doubt

Comment: He can use Tsukuyomi after implanting Itachi's eyes :)

Comment: @krikara He can not. See my answer to [this](http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/15018/9123) question.

Comment: @Sarenya See my [answer](http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/15018/9123) there.

Comment: @AmanSingh You can't really use the wikia page as proof. Look at the answer that was marked correct. Additionally, if you receive eyes from a person, you can use the same jutsus his eyes used (ie Danzou using Shisui's eye). Just because they don't explicitly say Sasuke used Tsukuyomi doesn't mean he hasn't. You also totally discounted the Bee fight because you said it was the "only time it happens". Even if Sasuke only used it once, he still used it.

Comment: @krikara The answer that was marked correct, is wrong. Anyway, I am not relying on the wiki. I have provided sufficient proof in my answer (which I suspect you haven't read completely). In the Bee fight, Sasuke still didn't have Itachi's eyes, and also, a black and white background doesn't mean Tsukuyomi. The eye Sasuke used for thi supposed "Tsukuyomi" is used for Amaterasu's shape manipulation (E.g Kagutsuchi), as seen in Kaguya fight. BTW, the wikia is maintained and cross checked by many more independent editors than here, with far more textual references.

Comment: How to know if certain Sasuke genjutsu is not Tsukuyomi. Such on the last ride he used a genjutsu on sakura. That seem to look like a Tsukuyomi.

Comment: @AmanSingh I've read your post; you try to reason that Sasuke is just using a normal genjutsu as opposed to Tsukuyomi. In any case, Sasuke can use Tsukuyomi because he received Itachi's eyes. When you receive eyes, you receive the inherent ocular powers as well. This occurs with all eye transfers in Naruto, whether it is Sharingan or Rinnegan.

Comment: @krikara You are arguing the conclusion as a premise. We have never seen an Uchiha, having a mangekyou, take his brother's mangekyou and gain the brother's powers. If we knew what Madara and Izuna's powers were, we could have concluded one way or the other. But here, the use of Tsukuyomi by Sasuke itself is in debate, seeing he has never used Tsukuyomi (that too is debatable it seems).

Comment: @Sarenya Not all genjutsu is Tsukuyomi. Tsukuyomi manipulates time length in victim's experience of the genjustu, like Itachi did with Kakashi and Sasuke. Attack on Sakura was almost instantaneous, and similar to Itachi's paralysing genjutsu he used on Orochimaru. Even the genjutsu used on the bijuu wasn't named Tsukuyomi by anyone; not by Rikudo, not by Sasuke, not even by the bijuu themselves. It was just called a "glance"

Comment: @krikara But since no one has ever seen Sasuke either in manga or in anime ever cast a genjutsu that controls the perception of victim's time in his genjutsu (which is the signature of Tsukuyomi), nor seen him utter the words "Tsukuyomi" with reference to ANY of his genjutsu, it is very unreasonable for anyone to assume that he has ever used Tsukuyomi.