# What Mangekyo Sharingan power does Itachi have?

Tags: naruto

Kakashi and Obito, have Mangekyo Sharingan powers but what power does Itachi have?

I tried researching it but nothing is helping.

Comment: also, mangekyo sharingan powers.

Comment: try to edit your question description to match with your title.

Comment: refer this [question](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/846/why-do-some-sharingan-eyes-have-unique-mangekyou-abilities?rq=1). I think it contains all Mangekyo Sharingan powers.

Answer (score 5):

Mangekyou Sharingan users have three abilities. Two unique ones in either eye, and Susano'o, which can only be used if you have Mangekyo Sharingan in both eyes. Itachi had Tsukuyomi in his left, and Amaterasu in his right. Sasuke had Amaterasu in his left eye, and could extinguish and control the shape of the flames in his left, as he did during his fight with Killer B, stopping B from being killed by the Amaterasu. Obito's Mangekyo both used different forms of Kamui, the left one he gave to Kakashi could uses a long range form that could teleport objects within the user's line of sight to the Kamui dimension. The right one he kept could only teleport himself and people he had physical contact with to the Kamui dimension. It also allows the user to become intangible, by teleporting the parts of themselves hit by attacks to the Kamui dimension. The full extent of Shisui's abilities are unknown, but both the eye that Shisui gave Itachi and the eye taken by Danzo could use Kotoamatsukami. The abilities of Madara and his brother were not revealed, but we know Madara was able to use Susano'o, meaning he unlocked the power of both his eyes.

However, Amaterasu and Tsukyomi are *not* generic Sharingan powers. While Sasuke had Amaterasu like Itachi, I believe that was due to them being closely related, and not because it was a generic power, because *no other* Mangekyo Sharingan user has demonstrated the ability to use either Amaterasu or Tsukuyomi, apart from Madara using Infinite Tsukuyomi, but I think it's safe to say that's a special case because of the Rinne Sharingan on his forehead.

Answer (score 3):

From the Naruto Wikia site under [Mangekyō Sharingan](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Mangeky%C5%8D_Sharingan#Itachi_Uchiha) (Itachi Uchiha):

> With the Mangekyō Sharingan, Itachi was able to use at least three powerful techniques. With his "left Mangekyō" he could use Tsukuyomi, an extremely powerful genjutsu that allowed him to distort the victim's perception of time, torturing their psyche for what seemed like days in a matter of seconds. With his "right Mangekyō" he could use Amaterasu, a ninjutsu which creates virtually-inextinguishable black flames at the user's focal point that continue to burn until the target is reduced to ash. The last of these known techniques was Susanoo, which allowed Itachi to summon a massive ethereal warrior.

As such we can conclude Itachi's powers are,

- [Tsukuyomi](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Tsukuyomi)
- [Amaterasu](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Amaterasu)
- [Susanoo](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Susanoo)

Comment: I guess, these powers can be used by any Mangekyo Sharingan user with little effort. And the question is about powers specific to Itachi's MS. Something like Kamui for Obito, Kotoamatsukami for Shisui etc.. But the question is not so clear.

Comment: @KaguyaOtsutsuki the question did only ask for Itachi's powers which the wikia only lists these 3 so it's possible he doesn't have any unique ability and i haven't seen as much of the series as most people (due to waiting for DVDs to buy in sets). it's quite possible Itachi's Mangekyō Sharingan isn't actually all that special, or he just was never able to reach the stage where he would develop a unique power like Kamui.

Comment: Still I can think of one special ability, His susanoo has '[Totsuka Sword](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sword_of_Totsuka)'.

Comment: @KaguyaOtsutsuki well under the data section on the right for the Susanoo and Totsuka Sword pages Sunasso's page lists it's classification (ie, being a Nin/Genjutsu) while the sword lists related tools and is listed in the same way on the page for [Sword of Kusanagi](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sword_of_Kusanagi_(Orochimaru)) while [Amaterasu: Dual Layer](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Amaterasu:_Dual_Layer) lists Susanoo as "other jutsu" (being derived from it). i'd rather call Totsuka Sword a tool/weapon than a power, though on the other hand that might just make Itachi's Susanoo more unique

Comment: Isn't Tsukuyomi Itachi's individual power.  No other person seemed to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The manga is not clear on this, but the idea many people seem to have is that Amaterasu and Tsukuyomi are two generic powers every Mangekyo user has and that Obito and Shisui had various bonus unique powers, but I don't think this is the case.

Neither Obito nor Shisui are ever shown to use either of these, my understanding is as follows:

Itachi, Sasuke: Amaterasu in one eye, Tsukuyimi in the other.

Obito: Kamui, close range in one eye, long range in the other (Kakashi's)

Shisui: Kotoamatsukami, perhaps in both eyes.

Madara: ?? I can't remember if this has been shown

And then any Mangekyo user who has awakened both powers will be able to use Susanoo.

Comment: Basically, I think there are a bunch of Mangekyo powers going around, and any Uchiha who awakens theirs gets two, Itachi and Sasuke share the same because they are brothers.

Answer (score 0):

Itachi

Left Eye : Tsukuyomi (powerful genjutsu)
Right Eye : Amatarasu (black flames)

Comment: I could be wrong but I thought all mangekyo sharingan users had Amatarasu?

Comment: Could you provide a source? Also extend your answer a little bit than it looks alot better :3

Comment: @Quikstryke No, not all people house Amaterasu in their eyes. Only Sasuke does because Itachi invoked a time-delay spell in his eye for Amaterasu. It is unique to Itachi and Sasuke.