# Why can’t Madara use Amaterasu or Kamui?

Tags: naruto

From what I've known, Madara was a legendary leader of the Uchiha clan. So, there are chances that he knew all types of techniques in terms of his eyes. His Kekkai Genkai includes:

- [Sharingan](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Madara_Uchiha#Sharingan)
- [Eternal Mangekyō Sharingan](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Madara_Uchiha#Mangeky.C5.8D_Sharingan)
- [Rinnegan](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Madara_Uchiha#Rinnegan)
- [Wood Release](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Wood_Release)
- [Storm Release](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Storm_Release)

So, I wonder why couldn’t Madara use Amaterasu or Kamui?

Comment: [Why do some Sharingan eyes have unique Mangekyou abilities?](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/846/why-do-some-sharingan-eyes-have-unique-mangekyou-abilities)

Comment: I may be wrong, but i believe Madara has to be able to use Tsukuyomi, Amaterasu.
I believe they mention Susanoo can only be obtain by possessing both those techniques. I always assumed madara never used it cause it's so beneath him. He also said himself sasukes fire style rivals mine.

Comment: False. Susanoo is unlocked when powers of both the eyes are mastered, regardless of what they are. The Fire Style is the Uchiha's common/signature technique, so the rivaling part is inconclusive.

Answer (score 8):

Madara can't use Kamui, because that was Obito Uchiha's Mangekyou Sharingan ability, used by Kakashi after the transplant (after part I). He could only use it because he took Kakashi's Sharingan and used it to access Obito's pocket dimension to retrieve the Rinnegan.

- Itachi - Tsukuyomi, Amaterasu, Susanoo
- Sasuke - Blaze Release: Kagutsuchi, Amaterasu, Susanoo
- Obito - Kamui, Susanoo
- Madara - Susanoo
- Izuna - Not mentioned in the series
- Shisui -  Kotoamatsukami, Susanoo
- Indra - Susanoo, Amaterasu

Madara can't use Amaterasu, because in my opinion, it's an ability that only runs in Sasuke and Itachi's family, seeing as they were the only ones to show this ability in the series.

All Mangekyou Sharingan users can use the Izanagi and Izanami ability.

Comment: Some corrections, 1. One doesn't need Mangekyou for Izanagi and Izanami 2. Obito didn't have Susanoo because he didn't have both MS eyes 3. Susanoo can be used by anyone who has both activated MS eyes

Comment: I think other uchihas may be able to use amaterasu but it put too much strain on one eyes that many decide not to use it. Itachi was crazy to use it. Sasuke uses it after getting eternal MS.

Comment: Sasuke had used the Amaterasu way before getting Itachi's eyes. He used it when retrieving Eight-Tails (Hachibi) and spammed it against Danzo. Then went blind. It was Itachi and Sasuke's specific ability, no other Uchiha can use it.

Answer (score 3):

Madara cant use Amaterasu nor can Kamui since his eyes do not grant that ability.
Kamui is Obito's ability (in both eyes) and Amaterasu is Itachi's (left eye) and Sasuke could use it only because Itachi gave it to him just before he died (Sasuke left eye also). In both eyes Itachi has Tsukiyomi.

Susanoo is accessible for all Mangekyou Sharingan users who possess two of the eyes (so Obito didnt have it and neither did Kakashi - for most of the time anyway).

Izanagi and Izanami are accessible for ALL SHARINGANS not just Mangekyou (Obito used Izanagi on his left eye while fighting Konan, which was an eye transplanted from some random no-name Uchiha corpse and also Danzou had 10 Sharingans for Izanagi and none of them was Mangekyou)

Comment: Note, Sasuke did not obtain Amaterasu because Itachi gave it to him. Sasuke obtained a one time use Amaterasu from Itachi, which was automatically used against Tobi (and his eye used Itachis Mangekyou to do it). He then awakened his own Star pattern Mangekyou, and he had Amaterasu. Itachi had Tsukuyomi, but could not control Amaterasu. Sasuke did not obtain Tsukuyomi, but instead got the ability to control the Amaterasu.